# Google Sheets Add-on not triggering custom events in GTM

Tags: google-apps-script, google-tag-manager, google-sheets-api, gtag.js

I am trying to fire GTM custom events from Google App Script Sidebar. A simplified version of the code is given below. The same code works if I test it locally on a local server as a web page. Events are triggered. But when it is part of an add-on the events are not getting triggered. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The HTML file is give below. This is displayed as a sidebar.
**Update: I have put the full working code. The same below code is firing the tags when I test is in local server. But is does not fire the tags when displayed as a sidebar in a google sheets add-on. I am suspecting that the html is displayed inside an iframe. Not sure why it is not working**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_blank">
    <script>
    dataLayer = [];
    </script>
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXXX');</script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script> 
    
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
    <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-TLGFLD7"
    height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->

    <div class="container main_page">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="report" id="report"  >Create Report</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        
        function ProcessReport() {
                dataLayer.push({'event':'run_report'});
                console.log(window.dataLayer);
        }
    
        
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $("#report").click(ProcessReport);
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function ProcessReport() {
        dataLayer.push({'event':'run_report'});
        console.log(window.dataLayer);
}


$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#report").click(ProcessReport());
});
```

Comment: I have done per your suggestion. It is not working. You can see the change in my updated code.